# Is there any way to merge different branches of sources?

Tags: svn, merge, controls, version, branch

Is there any way to merge different branches of sources?

I mean, I already had web application project source codes in SVN.
One month ago, my friend checked out this project and add more features and functions with his friend.

However, his project is not connected to the original SVN repository.

We have almost same structures of project but some different source codes.

Is there any good way to merge this sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert your repository from SVN to git. Git is more suited to distributed working like this (and it has other advantages over SVN, too). Ideally, you would have used git from the start, but you can still use git now.

Your friend should then clone your git repository into a new directory, copy his changed files over to the new directory, commit them and `git push` or email the commits to you using `get send-email`.

Comment: Thanks Robin. However, there are lots of conflict changes made by me and my friend. I mean, we already made changes to the same files. 
Is there any way to find out which files are conflict and which files are not conflicted at once when the sources came from different places.